# Strange lotus notes icon, what is it?

Tags: icons, lotus-notes

[image]

Do you know what is in this icon on the top right? Two to the left this a rocket for "launch". But the icon on the right I do not understand.
(I do not talk about the Lotus Notes function when you click on the icon, I only talk about what you see in this icon)

Comment: How is *What is this third-party software icon's image?* a programming question?

Comment: its a propeller hat, but I don't see how this question belongs to stackoverflow...

Comment: How is a "propeller hat" related to the properties tab?

Comment: Maybe it's because "propeller" and "property" can both be abbreviated as "prop". Who can guess the thoughts of whatever developer decided to use that icon 20+ years ago? In any case, as suggested by other commenters, the question is really off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation can be found in the [Hacker's Dictionary](https://www.hacker-dictionary.com/terms/propeller-head)

```
Propeller Head n. 
Used by hackers, this is syn. with "computer geek".
Non-hackers sometimes use it to describe all techies. Prob. derives
from SF fandom's tradition (originally invented by old-time fan Ray
Faraday Nelson) of propeller beanies as fannish insignia (though
nobody actually wears them except as a joke).
```

This was just a joke by the early developers of Lotus Notes, implying that only a real expert would be interested in the properties on this tab.